# Swift: How to enter edit mode for table?

Tags: swift

I have a RootViewController that embeds a container that contains a table:

[image]

I'd like the garbage can icon on the top left of the RootViewController to enable editing mode for the embedded table view. I would like them to show up as checkboxes so that I can select multiple rows at once and then press "Delete" to delete all of the selected ones.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully your class already conforms to `UITableViewDelegate` like so:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate
```

In `viewDidLoad()`, you would need to have:

```
myTable.delegate = self
```

Then you can hook up the trash can icon to an IBAction that sets the table to editing mode:

```
@IBAction func myTableSetEditing(sender: AnyObject) {        
    myTable.setEditing(true, animated: true)   
}
```

Then, as we see in an answer here: [Select multiple rows in tableview and tick the selected ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30516451/select-multiple-rows-in-tableview-and-tick-the-selected-ones), in `viewDidLoad()` put:

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

and to get your checkmark, implement:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
}
```

Comment: can i access `myTable` from the root controller if i have an outlet to the container view containing the table?

Comment: @Edmund http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440378/swift-accessing-and-updating-tableview-in-container-view

Comment: wow nice!! a combination of your answer and that answer got the select boxes to show

Comment: now i'm having trouble getting it to check on didSelectRowAtIndexPath