# Swift - Can't Pass Data through Custom Tab Pager in Nav Controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue, childviewcontroller

I followed a tutorial on how to implement a custom tab pager in a navigation controller. My setup looks like this. On the BuyStatsTapPager (on the right) you should see that you can switch between "buy" and "contest".

[image]

This basically works by instantiating view controllers depending on which child tab is clicked. The problem is that I also have data in this class (I have successfully set 'var selectedPlayerBuyStats' from the previous view controller prepare for segue method) that I need to pass to the instantiated controllers.

Down at the bottom in 'updateView()'I thought I had a way figured out because I'm able to access the child view controllers tableview to set its size and dimension. I have the lines commented out that aren't working. The IDE is successfully finding the property off of the child view controllers that I need to set, but when I actually try to get the data in the child view controller its nil. Is there another way I could maybe try to do this? Thanks

```
import UIKit



class BuyStatsTabPager: BuyStats{


@IBOutlet var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreKey: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var standings: UIBarButtonItem!

var selectedPlayerBuyStats: Player! = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {

    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 27/255, green: 27/255, blue: 27/255, alpha: 1)

    scoreKey.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 13.0)!], for: UIControlState.normal)
    scoreKey.tintColor = UIColor.blue

    standings.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 13.0)!], for: UIControlState.normal)
    standings.tintColor = UIColor.blue


    setupView()
}

private func setupView() {
    setupSegmentedControl()
    updateView()
}

private func setupSegmentedControl() {
    // Configure Segmented Control
    segmentedControl.removeAllSegments()
    segmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: "Buy", at: 0, animated: false)
    segmentedControl.insertSegment(withTitle: "Score", at: 1, animated: false)
    segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(selectionDidChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
}

func selectionDidChange(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    updateView()
}


private lazy var viewContestTab: BuyStatsTab = {
    // Load Storyboard
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

    // Instantiate View Controller
    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BuyStatsTab") as! BuyStatsTab


    // Add View Controller as Child View Controller
    self.add(asChildViewController: viewController)

    return viewController
}()

private lazy var viewRoundTab: BuyStatsContestTab = {
    // Load Storyboard
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

    // Instantiate View Controller
    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BuyStatsContestTab") as! BuyStatsContestTab




    // Add View Controller as Child View Controller
    self.add(asChildViewController: viewController)

    return viewController
}()

private func add(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    // Add Child View Controller
    addChildViewController(viewController)

    // Add Child View as Subview
    view.addSubview(viewController.view)

    // Configure Child View
    viewController.view.frame = view.bounds
    viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    // Notify Child View Controller
    viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}

private func remove(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    // Notify Child View Controller
    viewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)

    // Remove Child View From Superview
    viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()

    // Notify Child View Controller
    viewController.removeFromParentViewController()
}

private func updateView() {
    if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {

        //this is working so I have the data I need to pass
        print(selectedPlayerBuyStats.p)

        let position = viewRoundTab.tableView.contentOffset.y;
        viewContestTab.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x:0, y:position);

        //but it isn't working this way
        //viewContestTab.selectedPlayer = selectedPlayerBuyStats


        remove(asChildViewController: viewRoundTab)
        add(asChildViewController: viewContestTab)
    } else {


        print(selectedPlayerBuyStats.Name)

        let position = viewContestTab.tableView.contentOffset.y;
        viewRoundTab.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x:0, y:position);

        //viewRoundTab.selectedPlayer = selectedPlayerBuyStats

        remove(asChildViewController: viewContestTab)
        add(asChildViewController: viewRoundTab)
    }
}


}
```

EDIT:

So I'm trying to use prepare for segue in the tab pager class but still having problems. 1. I don't know how to check which child class the data should go to. 2. Even if I just send like this to the first child class the data is still nil on the other side.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {


        let buyStats = segue.destination as! BuyStatsTab

        buyStats.selectedPlayer = selectedPlayer


}
```

Here is the first of the recipient child view controllers.

```
class BuyStatsTab: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

let cellReuseIdentifier = "cell"

var stats = [BuyStat]()

var selectedPlayer: Player! = nil


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 70.0
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self


    stats = [
             BuyStat(purchaseAmount: 0.0, category: "Pts", average: selectedPlayer.p, price: "$75"),
             BuyStat(purchaseAmount: 0.0, category: "Reb", average: 6.5, price: "$175"),
             BuyStat(purchaseAmount: 0.0, category: "Ast", average: 6.7, price: "$200"),
             BuyStat(purchaseAmount: 0.0, category: "Stl", average: 2.2, price: "$300"),
             BuyStat(purchaseAmount: 0.0, category: "Blk", average: 0.4, price: "$325"),
             BuyStat(purchaseAmount: 0.0, category: "3pt", average: 3.3, price: "$325"),
             BuyStat(purchaseAmount: 0.0, category: "TO", average: 2.4, price: "$350")]

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

selectedPlayer.p in the array should have data.

Comment: You need to pass the data via prepare for segue just like you did it to get `var selectedPlayerBuyStats` value passed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try but I'm still a little confused because I don't have a segue identifier.

Comment: Try making the viewContestTab variable not lazy

Comment: Have a look at this and see if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31440378/swift-accessing-and-updating-tableview-in-container-view

Comment: @ Timmy, thank for the reply. Seems like it could have to do with the child view controllers being lazy, but when I remove that I get an error under 'self.add(asChildViewController: viewController)'. I get 'Value of type NSObject -> () -> BuyStatsTapPager has no member add'. I'll keep trying things.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments I was able to get to the exact answer. I just had to set the data inside of the lazy variable viewContestTab instead of down further in the updateView(). I thought doing it in updateView() would work because the tutorial had me access the tableview from there. I'm still not sure why I can access the tableview in updateView() but not set the other data. If anyone thinks this deserves a better explanation I'll gladly give them best answer.

```
 private lazy var viewRoundTab: BuyStatsContestTab = {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BuyStatsContestTab") as! BuyStatsContestTab

    viewController.selectedPlayer = self.selectedPlayerBuyStats

    self.add(asChildViewController: viewController)

    return viewController
}()
```